# Block selection when loading Layout

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I load and process my layout, but I have an `if` in my controller and, depending on the value that I need, I have to load a specific block. How can I create it?

**My controller :**

public function finalizeAction()
{

```
if (Some_if)
{

}
elseif (some_if)
{

}
elseif (someif)
{

}
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

}

**My layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <agentdeposit_order_finalize>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/finalizeorder.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="agentdeposit/finalize" name="agentdeposit_finalize" template="agentdeposit/finalize_form.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </agentdeposit_order_finalize>
</layout>
```

I render just finalize_form.phtml, but I want to render 4 values depending on if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function finalizeAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    if (Some_if)
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'block_name1')->setTemplate('path/to/template1.phtml');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    }
    elseif (some_if)
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'block_name2')->setTemplate('path/to/template2.phtml');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    }
    elseif (someif)
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'block_name3')->setTemplate('path/to/template3.phtml');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    }
    $this->renderLayout();

}
```

You dont need with this to set the templates in your xml.